# OAuth 2 Device Flow redirect url

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I was exploring the OAuth 2 device flow recently - and came across this url

`urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`

The service asked me to keep this as the redirect URL if I was using device flow.

I also read this whole paper https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-device-flow-06 and there is no mention of such a URL.

I was hoping to find out more information about this and any resources on the internet where its origins were discussed.

**EDIT**

I found the following - https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/oauth/current/msg09988.html

The person also asks for clarification on why is this URL absent from OAuth 2 spec.

But it does not seem to have a precise response from anyone.

Comment: I think this is the answer you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12712923/88122

Comment: That answer explains its use, which I am already aware of. I am looking for an IETF approved paper where this kind of a URL is mentioned or recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information I have been able to obtain, the "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" has been replaced with [OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps (RFC 8252](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252)) using the [Private-Use URI Scheme Redirection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-7.1)

The [Google page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp) shows deprecation notices in options 3 and 4 in the "create authorization credentials" section; you can find the "oob" URN later in the doc, associated with the same options.

More details from the [OAUTH-WG](https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/msg/oauth/5CkOmL7sP2f_gHcbwknSY0MD60w)